# sql auto increment based on ID

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, sql-server-2017

Im using SQLServer 2017, I have a table that I want to auto increment for each id.
Example Table A has columns

> PolicyID, ClaimID, TranId

with the following values

> ABC123, 111, 1

when another row gets inserted/added TranId will show 2 and so on but if the PolicyID is different lets say ABC456 then the expected TranId should be 1 but my table just keeps incrementing instead of per PolicyID.

Comment: Hi, can you show what you have tried? have you looked at a ranking function like `row_number() over(partition by column1, ..., column_n, order by column 1)`

Comment: I think what you're saying you want to do is store this value in the table; this is a bad idea. Why? Well, the problem is that if another row is added/deleted/updated it may mean that other rows will need to be amended as well, and hence why it's not a good idea. Thus, instead, you would be better creating a `VIEW` which had this value. `ROW_NUMBER()` is a good example, as @MCP_infiltrator has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a sequence and this shouldn't be stored in the table.

Try creating a view:

```
create vw_xxx as
(
select PolicyID, ClaimID
      , TranId = row_number() over (partition by PolicyID order by ClaimID)
from tableXXX
)
```

This is an example of how to do this. You need to partition and order by properly to get the right sequence.

If this table is large then you want to have an index on the partition,ordered by columns.

Comment: Thank you Keith for this, I had seen a few statements like this but I struggle to understand the row_number() and partition functions.

Comment: Partition is what you are splitting data by and order is the order.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you enter a new row in your `MyTable` you have to run the following `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET Table_A.TranId = Table_B.[TranId]
FROM MyTable AS Table_A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PolicyID, ClaimID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyID, ClaimID ORDER BY ClaimID) AS [TranId]
```

FROM MyTable
    ) Table_B
     ON Table_A.PolicyID = Table_B.PolicyID AND Table_A.ClaimID = Table_B.ClaimID